# ¿Como copiar los datos de una tabla de una base de datos en otra base de datos con una tabla idéntica?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Saludos a todos, amigos. Tengo el siguiente problema:

Acabo de asumir la administración de un antiguo sistema el cual maneja 4 bases de datos (nombres distintos, estructura idéntica) pero la única tabla común en estructura y datos es la de Usuarios.

El sistema según me informan tiene una tarea que toma la tabla de una de las bases de datos como principal y la replica en las otras 3 :S, esta tarea está fallando y el sistema esta caído... :$

Si bien debo buscar en que parte de ese horrible código esta dicha tarea, **me urge hacer la replica de las tablas de forma manual vía SQL Server**.

He intentado esto:

```
UPDATE [BDdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios]

SET
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].activo = [Usuarios].activo,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].apellido = [Usuarios].apellido,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].cargo = [Usuarios].cargo,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].correo = [Usuarios].correo,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].nombre = [Usuarios].nombre,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].password = [Usuarios].password,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].usuario_id = [Usuarios].usuario_id

FROM [DBorigen].[dbo].[Usuarios]
```

Pero me da este error:

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Los objetos
>   "DBdestino.dbo.Usuarios" y "DBorigen.dbo.Usuarios" en la cláusula FROM
>   tienen los mismos nombres expuestos. Use nombres de correlación para
>   distinguirlos.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que un `UPDATE` es lo que quieres? ¿Tienes garantía que para cada registro en tu tabla fuente también tienes un registro en la tabla de destino? Y aunque fuera así (que lo dudo), aparte del problema de sintaxis en tu sentencia, también tienes el problema que no hay condición en tu join, por lo que de seguro estarás corrompiendo tus datos.  Si quieres una réplica, ¿por qué no hacer un `delete + insert`, o tal vez un `merge`?

Comment: UMMMM... cierto es lo quue me ocurre ahora ... :$ 
como seria el {delete + insert} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres hacer una réplica de los datos de una tabla usando SQL, en realidad una sentencia `UPDATE` no te conviene, porque tal vez tengas registros de más o menos en ambas tablas, y en esos casos, el `UPDATE` no te ayudará.

Mas bien, una opción es borrar todos los datos y volver a insertar todos los datos de tu tabla fuente:

```
delete from [BDdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios];

insert into [BDdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios] select * from [DBorigen].[dbo].[Usuarios];
```

Si es posible, en vez del `DELETE`, pudieras optar por usar un `TRUNCATE TABLE` si deseas.

En cualquier caso, si tu tablas contiene una columna `identity` (`usuario_id`?), necesitarás correr la sentencia siguiente antes de hacer el `INSERT`:

```
set identity_insert [BDdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios] on;
```

---

Otra opción que puede que sea más eficiente es usar un `MERGE`, que básicamante se encarga de hacer los `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` necesarios para que tu tabla de destino se convierta en una réplica de tu tabla fuente. Puede ser más eficiente si la mayoría de los registros ya concuerdan entre las 2 tablas:

```
merge into [BDdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios] as dest
using [DBorigen].[dbo].[Usuarios] as src
   on src.usuario_id = dest.usuario_id
when matched then 
  update set dest.activo = src.activo,
             dest.apellido = src.apellido,
             dest.cargo = src.cargo,
             dest.correo = src.correo,
             dest.nombre = src.nombre,
             dest.password = src.password
when not matched then 
  insert (usuario_id, activo, apellido, cargo, correo, nombre, password)
  values (src.usuario_id, src.ctivo, src.apellido, src.cargo, src.correo, src.nombre, src.password)
when not matched by source then delete;
```

Con el `MERGE` también, si tu columna `usuario_id` es una columna `identity`, necesitarás ejecutar le sentencia siguiente antes del `MERGE`:

```
set identity_insert [BDdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios] on;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si las 2 bases estan en el mismo server puedes usar un alias que te evita este inconveniente.

```
UPDATE [BDdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios]
SET
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].activo = usu1.activo,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].apellido = usu1.apellido,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].cargo = usu1.cargo,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].correo = usu1.correo,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].nombre = usu1.nombre,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].password = usu1.password,
[DBdestino].[dbo].[Usuarios].usuario_id = usu1.usuario_id

FROM [DBorigen].[dbo].[Usuarios] usu1

where 
[dbo].[Usuarios].usuario_id = usu1.usuario_id
```

Comment: Cuidado, esta sentencia te va a corromper los datos porque no hay condición en el join.

Comment: Correcto la corri y ahora hay la misma cantidad de registros pero todos son el primero repetido... :C

Comment: Ahi modifique la consulta que faltaba la condición del join